# Create category based on keyword in R

Tags: r, categories, lookup, lookup-tables

I have a dataframe containing two columns: 1st column is the keyword and 2nd is the associated category.

```
keywords <- c("keyword1", "keyword2", "keyword3")
categories <- c("category1", "category2", "category3")

lookup_table <- data.frame(keywords, categories)
```

I would like that each time I have a new label, I check whether there is a category corresponding to it and if so, attach the category.

So for the following example below, there would be the value 'category1' attached to the first row in a new column:

```
new_labels <- c("keyword1 qefjhqek", "hfaef", "fihiz")
```

Help much appreciated!

Comment: Just check out the `grep` and `grepl` to check if you have already assigned a category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here just use `str_extract` to get the relevant text and join the reference table.

```r
keywords <- c("keyword1", "keyword2", "keyword3")
categories <- c("category1", "category2", "category3")

lookup_table <- data.frame(keywords, categories)
new_labels <- c("keyword1 qefjhqek", "hfaef", "fihiz")

library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
ref_tbl <- 
# data.table(
# For the AntoniosK's sugguestion, recommend dplyr-like function.
tibble(
    keywords = keywords
    ,categories = categories
)

# as.data.table(
# For the AntoniosK's sugguestion, recommend dplyr-like function.
as_tibble(
    new_labels
    ) %>% 
    mutate(ref_key = str_extract(new_labels
                                 # ,'keyword[:digit:]'
                                 ,(
                                   keywords %>% 
                                     str_flatten('|')
                                   # regular expression
                                 )
                                 )) %>% 
    left_join(
         ref_tbl
         ,by=c('ref_key'='keywords')
    )
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   value             ref_key  categories
#>   <chr>             <chr>    <chr>     
#> 1 keyword1 qefjhqek keyword1 category1 
#> 2 hfaef             <NA>     <NA>      
#> 3 fihiz             <NA>     <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

---

From @AntoniosK's question, I do the comparison between `data.table` and `tibble`. And the fact is there is a significant sign supporting `tibble` is better than `data.table`.

1. `tibble` only 2990 ms -> 1st 
   : [image]
2. `data.table` and `as.data.table` 3240 ms -> 2nd
   : [image]
3. `data.table` only 3840 ms -> 3rd
   : [image]

Comment: Your solution is correct, but very specific and tailored to the example data posted. :) What if `keywords` vector doesn't include "keyword", but has values that don't match a specific set of characters? Like `keywords <- c("apple", "orange", "banana")`.

Comment: Hi @AntoniosK, I edit my code and update a regular expression rule to meet the new condition `keywords <- c("apple", "orange", "banana")`.

Comment: That's great! I've updated my answer as well including an approach that uses `str_extract`. Why do you use `data.table` as well? :)

Comment: Because this data type is faster than `tibble` and `data.frame`.

Comment: I'm not sure you use `data.table` 's speed when using `dplyr` commands. If you want to get some, or most, of it check package `dtplyr` and do some comparisons yourself to double check.

Comment: @AntoniosK  you are right. I do a test but the result shows the tibble is best, which changes my mind because I always choose data.table first before. Thank you for your reminder. You can check my comparison I update on my answer.

Comment: I think the faster one would be to use only `data.table` package. And I mean `data.table` as your data object and `data.table` commands. No `dplyr` at all.

Comment: @AntoniosK I agree with you, the hybrid way makes the solution worse.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution that creates all combinations between your new labels and keywords, spots matches and extracts the keywords and then join the categories from the lookup table:

```
keywords <- c("keyword1", "keyword2", "keyword3")
categories <- c("category1", "category2", "category3")
lookup_table <- data.frame(keywords, categories)

new_labels = c("keyword1 qefjhqek", "hfaef", "fihiz")

library(tidyverse)

expand.grid(new_labels=new_labels, keywords=lookup_table$keywords) %>%  # create all combinations
  mutate_all(as.character) %>%                                          # update to character (if needed)
  mutate(v = map2_lgl(new_labels, keywords, ~grepl(.y, .x))) %>%        # check if there's a match
  group_by(new_labels) %>%                                              # for each new label
  summarise(keywords = ifelse(sum(v) > 0, keywords[v==TRUE], NA)) %>%   # get the keyword if there is one
  left_join(lookup_table, by="keywords") %>%                            # join categoris
  select(-keywords)                                                     # remove keywords

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   new_labels        categories
#   <chr>             <fct>     
# 1 fihiz             NA        
# 2 hfaef             NA        
# 3 keyword1 qefjhqek category1
```

And an alternative version inspired by @Jianxiang 's answer that uses `str_extract` to get the relevant keyword, instead of creating all combinations:

```
data.frame(new_labels) %>%
  mutate(keywords = str_extract(new_labels, str_flatten(lookup_table$keywords, "|"))) %>%
  left_join(lookup_table, by="keywords") %>%        
  select(-keywords)

#           new_labels categories
# 1 keyword1 qefjhqek  category1
# 2             hfaef       <NA>
# 3             fihiz       <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(
    label = new_labels,
    keywords = unlist(
      map2(new_labels, paste(lookup_table$keywords, collapse = "|"), str_extract)
    )) %>% 
    left_join(lookup_table) %>%
    select(- keywords)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
#   label             categories
#   <chr>             <fct>   
# 1 keyword1 qefjhqek category1
# 2 hfaef             <NA>    
# 3 fihiz             <NA>
```